# Guardian pattern. Trying to understand why/how the length of 'no input' can be greater than 0 when evaluated

Tags: python

```
while True:
    line = input('> ')
    if len(line) > 0 and line[0] == '#' :
        continue
    if line == 'done':
        break
    print line
print ("done!")
```

#So if there are no zeroth character then the length of the line is greater than 0?

Comment: The length of "no input" is zero.  Your first conditional has two requirements to meet: length greater than zero and an octothorpe at index 0.  If you have no input, then a blank line will be sent to stdout since the default for Python's print function is to append a newline character (`\n`) to the end of a print statement.  Only if `done` is entered will the program exit.  If `#abc` is entered, nothing will print because the conditionals are met and the loop continues to a fresh input statement.

Comment: Thx now i understand that part.

Comment: while True:
    line = input('> ')
    if line[0] == '#':
        continue
    if line == 'done':
        break
    print(line)
print('Done!')

Comment: But why does it give a traceback when we remove the greater than condition annd an empty line is entered?

Comment: According to the docs: "When EOF is read, EOFError is raised."  So, if the user doesn't provide input, an `EOF` is the only option left, which produces the error you noted.  (See: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#input)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a logical error:

Even if the length of the string return by this function `len()` is 0 for empty input it won't stop since the `breaking` criteria only meets when the input string is `"done"`

so the length of `no input i.e empty input` is 0 but the terminal condition didn't meet